# Call function without button click

Tags: python, kivy

I want to ask simple question how to call a function in kivy without button Click. I have a project now and I want to call function once on program start and I don't know how to do this.

Comment: Call the function in your app's build method.

Answer (score 0):

So this will call function on start

```
class InfoWindow(Screen):

def __init__(self, **kwargs):
    super(InfoWindow, self).__init__(**kwargs)
    Clock.schedule_once(self.next_page)

def next_page(self, *args):
....
```